# Sizeof operator not giving correct size of pointer in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof, calloc

I created a structure with 3 integer members and a pointer variable ptr

```
 ptr=(struct node*)calloc(15,sizeof(struct node*));
  printf("%ld",sizeof(ptr));
```

however using the sizeof operator to get the size of ptr is printing a size less than 15(i.e. 8).
What should be done to just get the size of the pointer variable if this is incorrect.

Comment: It *is* returning the size of the pointer: a pointer on your system is 8 bytes, regardless of what it points to.  What you want is the allocated size of the buffer that the pointer points to, and C doesn't give you a way to query that; you have to keep track for yourself how much memory you allocated.

Comment: Sizeof returns the numbers of bytes, it doesn't work as you think.

Comment: By the way, passing `sizeof(struct node *)` to `calloc` is almost certainly a mistake; if `ptr` is to point to an array of `struct node`s, then you want space for 15 `struct`s, not 15 pointers.  You should have `sizeof(struct node)` there instead.

Comment: Even better would be `ptr=calloc(15,sizeof(*ptr));`

Comment: Best to use specifier `"%zu"`, not  `"%ld"`, when printing the result of `sizeof`

Answer (score 2):

The result you have obtained is totally as expected. 
Indeed, `sizeof(ptr)` returns the size of a pointer, which depends on your processor architecture (As it returns `8` you are very likely on a 64-bit processor).

Comment: or 2 or 3. There are smaller architectures than 16bits

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland "3" ? - most rare/unusual.  PIC24?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica AVR if named address spaces are used.

Comment: ***`__memx

    This is a 24-bit address space that linearizes flash and RAM:`

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland That's absolutely right yes ! Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The size of a pointer will depend on your hardware... A pointer stores an address in memory that represents the beggining of that thing you are allocating. It doesn't how matter how big that thing is: It's initial address will have the same number of bytes as any other variable.

The line `ptr=(struct node*)calloc(15,sizeof(struct node*));` is allocating space for 15 pointers, not 15 structs, you probably want to remove the `*` in the sizeof.

After you fix that, you can add the two lines to see the difference:

```
printf("size of a pointer to node* is: %d\n", sizeof(ptr));
printf("size of a struct pointed by a node* is :%d\n", sizeof(*ptr));
```